# Enforce a particular condition in ER diagram

Tags: database, entity-relationship, erd

I started studying databases today and I am trying to draw an ER diagram for a problem like: There are various companies that release several advertisements. Candidate see the ads, apply and some of them face interview. there must be 1 candidate at least to face the interview. Now I have drawn a simple ER diagram as shown below. But I am not very confident about it. Do I need to improve it to enforce the condition that **only some of those who have applied can face interviews.** How to represent that anyone who face the interview must have applied for it? If so, then how can I improve it to incorporate this situation? I haven't shown the attributes attached to entities here.

[image]

**Edit:** Adjusted the cardinalities and converted ternary relation Applies_for to a binary one as reeanb suggested.

[image: ER diagram version 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Applies_for is optional in both directions.  Are you going to record candidates that don't apply?
2. The company that a candidate applies to is implied via the Releases relationship, and don't need to be recorded separately.
3. You say there must be 1 candidate at least to face the interview, but the cardinality of Faces indicate that an interview doesn't require candidates.
4. Is it correct that candidates can face multiple interviews?
5. Whether you need to improve it to enforce the condition that only some of those who have applied can face interviews, depends on you or the assignment.  This is a requirements decision.
6. How to represent: you need to turn Applies_for into an entity (maybe call it Applications), and then Faces relates applications to interviews.  Remember to check the cardinalities.

Comment: No sorry the candidate must apply for at least 1 advertisement. Thanks for pointing that out.  And yes messed up the cardinality in case of faces relationship. Must be the reverse of what I wrote. Letme update the questions.

Comment: If you want to revise the description/diagram, I suggest you append it to your question instead of replacing the existing content so as not to invalidate the existing answer.  I'll do the same with additional feedback.  The progression of your diagram will be more educational to other viewers than just the final correct answer.

Comment: Ok I have done that, thanks . Looks better now? Or still needs improvement provided I don't represent the condition I talked about.

Comment: Looking much better.  Do you want to give 6 a try?

Comment: Yes. Candidate can give multiple interviews, but oh not for the same job. He can give multiple interviews for different jobs, and yes I am trying that :)

Comment: Will making Applies_for ternary again this time adding an entity named Applications with it and then, instead of linking candidates to interviews via relation faces, linking applications to interviews be good enough?

Comment: Changing Applies_for into an entity and adding a relationship to Interview will result in an entity with 3 binary relationships, not a ternary relationship.  I'm not sure what you have in mind, show me and I'll let you know.

Comment: Something like that I may be fundamentally wrong though.

Comment: Take a look at http://college.yukondude.com/2006_09_comp210/html/note.php?note=03%5ELecture_Notes%5ETernary_Relationships.tpl